# Number plus number from array in loops

Tags: python

For example array [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] it must be 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 6. so how is the result in these loops? so look below the script

```
    number = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
    
    for x in number:
        x + x
    
    print(x)
```

Comment: Maybe `sum(number)`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just add a `+=` and a new variable like so:

```
number = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
y = 0 #new variable (output variable)
for x in number:
    y += x #add = sign here

print(y)
```

Output:

```
18
```

But it would be better to use:

```
y = sum(number)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
18
```

Comment: I'm going to guess you haven't actually tried to execute this for any other list.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes I did, see the out put

Comment: No you didn't. You've edited the code since his comment.

Comment: @sagi yes I will continuously update to improve the answer, is that a problem?

Comment: There is no problem with updating your answer. There is a problem with denying your initial answer was wrong.

Comment: No, that's not a problem. The problem was your first answer that was just wrong.

Comment: Improvement is obviously not a problem; claiming your original version worked when it did not is.

Comment: @ScottHunter when did I claim that?

Comment: @Matthias hence the update

Comment: "Yes I did, see the output" clearly suggests that his comment was wrong, when it wasn't. "You are right, fixed" was probably what you needed to say.

Comment: @sagi no it suggest that now that I have updated the question to include the output that it has been tested and works.

Comment: "'You are right, fixed' was probably what you needed to say." Well I would have, but I noticed the error and edited before I saw the comment, so I was answering that I had already tested and updated.

Comment: I apologize if it was confusing for anyone, the answer is now proper, so no worries.

Comment: @ScottHunter I was quoting him he did not say "I."

Comment: @EliHarold: My apologies; pronouns can be hard :)

Comment: Sorry i'm new beginner coding

Comment: sir @EliHarold how do you start 0 plus 1 then add 2 and so on in loops?

Comment: @fauzi_dhuhuri are you asking about how to print all numbers? (say up to a certain number)

Comment: yes sir @EliHarold, yesterday I made a mean script from 6th-grade math. so sorry if I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @EliHarold I still don't understand the mathematical logic of the mean. sorry I made a question in public. I should make a question about the math mean

Comment: @fauzi_dhuhuri just change the first line to `number =  range(n)` where `n` is any integer number.

Comment: @EliHarold do you have Twitter? we can chat on Twitter

Comment: @fauzi_dhuhuri no I do not, sorry.

Comment: @EliHarold It's okay, where can we chat? because there are too many in the comments here. we can talk

Comment: @fauzi_dhuhuri Join this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/241930/discussion?tab=general

Comment: @EliHarold Sorry, I can't write because I have to have 20 reputations to chat

Comment: @EliHarold So where else can we chat?

Comment: @EliHarold If there's no place we can chat, it's okay